# Polly retry policy outcome always successful regardless of actual response

Tags: c#, .net, restsharp, polly

I'm trying to take advantage of [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly)'s ability to handle arbitrary result conditions https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/#step-1b-optionally-specify-return-results-you-want-to-handle.

In my test case I'm using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) to make HTTP requests.  Here's my sample code:

```
var policy = Policy
    .HandleResult<IRestResponse>(r => r.Content.Contains("bla"))
    .Retry(2)
    .ExecuteAndCapture(() =>
        {
            IRestClient client = new RestClient("https://httpbin.org/anything");
            IRestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            var response = client.Execute(request);
            return response;
        });
```

The call to https://httpbin.org/anything echos back a bunch of stuff - the exact content isn't relevant.  As you can see in the predicate I'm looking for the string "bla" in the result body.

The problem is that `policy.Outcome` is *always* successful (`policy.Outcome == OutcomeType.Successful`) but "bla" is *not* in the result body.

Comment: The `.HandleResult<TResult>(Func<TResult, bool>)` clause specifies `TResult`s you want to be considered *failures* - `TResult` values which should (in this case) trigger a retry.  If "bla" is _not_ in the result body, the result will be considered a success, a retry will not be made, and you will (expected behaviour) get `.Outcome == OutcomeType.Successful`.  If I have not understood - could you clarify the last sentence of your question?

Comment: @mountaintraveller Oy vey.  You're absolutely correct, I reversed the logic in my mind and specified a success condition rather than a failure condition...  Thank you for pointing out it.  I'm not sure if this question should remain on SO since the answer is just user-error.  I may close...  What do you think?

Comment: Fine to close.  I double-checked that we have a unit-test in Polly covering this case and we do: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/master/src/Polly.SharedSpecs/PolicyTResultSpecs.cs#L50

Comment: @mountaintraveller Ah great - thanks for pointing me to that.  Thanks again...

Comment: @mountaintraveller Re-thought about this - maybe makes sense to leave open - others could make same mistake.  You want to make an answer with the info in your first comment (plus the unit test link) and I'll mark as accepted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `.HandleResult<TResult>(Func<TResult, bool>)` clause specifies `TResult`s you want to be considered failures - `TResult` values which should (in this case) trigger a retry. If "bla" is not in the result body, the result will be considered a success, a retry will not be made, and you will (expected behaviour) get `.Outcome == OutcomeType.Successful`.

The following unit-test in the Polly codebase demonstrates how `.ExecuteAndCapture(...)` is returning `OutcomeType.Failure` when it should: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/73fc38029f52d2e1bfa6f4b03bcb1e12d8c78065/src/Polly.SharedSpecs/PolicyTResultSpecs.cs#L50